VK ADS banner in Android apps
You need to place the code in the application to display the advertising banner. There are instructions, but I can’t figure it out. https://ads.vk.com/help/articles/partner_android_banner
The task is simple.
There is a MainАctivity and activity_maim.xml. I am writing in Java.
How to place the code so that when the application starts, activity with a banner is displayed? I previously installed AdMob, but I can’t figure it out.
